# Optimizing CSS during a dojo build - using dojo 1.5.2

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, minify

I'm trying to optimize my CSS files (inline all @imports, and remove lines) but I'm not sure how to do it? Someone on the IRC room told me about packages, but looks like packages is not supported in dojo 1.5.2's build system: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/quickstart/custom-builds.html

My build profile looks like this ( I added the packages part, but no avail ): http://pastebin.com/4wqca6iy

Can someone please help? Is it even possible to optimize CSS outside the dojo folder in dojo 1.5.2?

Thanks,

Vikas.